# jquery.validationEngine.js dropwdown

Tags: php, jquery, forms

Im using `jquery.validationEngine.js` everything is setup and working fine, however I need to make a change.

I have two dropdown boxes.

Is The Vehicle Imported? [yes, no]
What Is The Country Of Origin? [France, Germany, Japan, USA, UK] etc

What I require is that if the car is imported then to show the country of origin, else display nothing.

At the moment I have both fields working on a live form,

```
<label>Is The Vehicle Imported?</label>
<select class="validate[required] target" name="strLeadData39" id="strLeadData39">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
</select>

<label>What Is The Country Of Origin?</label>
<select class="validate[required] target" name="strLeadData40" id="strLeadData40" >
    <option selected="selected" value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="Not Imported">Not Imported</option>
    <option value="France">France</option>
    <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
    <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
    <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
    <option value="USA">USA</option>
    <option value="EU-Other">EU-Other</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

How do Ш complete this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So you want to show/hide the country `select` depending on the value of the imported `select`?

```
$('#strLeadData39').change(function(){
    if ( $(this).val() == "Yes" ){
        $('#strLeadData40').show();
    } else {
        $('#strLeadData40').hide();
    }
});
```

[Here is a fiddle with a basic example](http://jsfiddle.net/vwv6crpo/)

The above code has nothing to do with jQuery validationEngine,just hiding/displaying the element. To make the form validate you will probably have to dynamically remove/add the `validate[required]` class using jQuery `removeClass/addClass`, something inside the if/else like:

```
$('#strLeadData40').removeClass("validate[required]");
```